# Converting timestamp to milli seconds since epoch

Tags: java, timestamp, jodatime, simpledateformat, epoch

Currently I am reading a data file line by line. Each line has a time stamp in the format **dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"**
I need to convert this into milli seconds since epoch. I tried two ways

1> Using standard library

```
timestamp  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(ddMMyyyy + " " + HHmmss);
return timestamp.getTime();
```

2> This is using Joda-Time Library

```
jiffy = format.parseMillis(ddMMyyyy + " " + HHmmss);
```

After profiling, I found that method one is incredibly expensive whereas method two is a bit less expensive than first one but still expensive. First one takes Aprox 1600ms of CPU time and second one takes 1100ms  of CPU time .

**Questions -**

1> Is there any better library which is not so expensive ?

2> If there is no standard library, can someone point me to conversion logic ? I tried googling but no success. There are few formulas on this site but they don't work or lets call it then they are not simple enough.

Thanks

**

## Adding more details on the question

**

ok..adding more details here.
The test run is for 10 million records. Each line has timestamp which needs to be converted into milli seconds since epoch.

Here are the three versions of code which i tried.

1> With Joda-Time - So far the best result but not acceptable.**It spends 26.9% of the time in time-conversion.**

```
long jiffy = 0;
public double getTime( String ddMMyyyy, String HHmmss) throws ParseException
{       
    jiffy = format.parseMillis(ddMMyyyy + " " + HHmmss);
    return jiffy/1000;
}
```

Here is the profiling 
http://postimg.org/image/bvrt3esgr/

2> With SimpleTimeFormat java class. **If a am using the same object again than it takes 36.1% doing this task.**

```
private long timestamp;
public static final SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",Locale.ENGLISH);
long jiffy = 0;

public double getTime( String ddMMyyyy, String HHmmss) throws ParseException
{
    timestamp = SDF.parse(ddMMyyyy + " " + HHmmss).getTime();
    return timestamp;
}
```

Here is the profile
http://postimg.org/image/72iua8x9j/
3> With SimpleTimeFormat java class. **If a am creating new object than it takes 51.6% doing this task.**

```
public long getTimei( String ddMMyyyy, String HHmmss) throws ParseException
{
    timestamp  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(ddMMyyyy + " " + HHmmss);
    return timestamp.getTime();
}
```

Here is the profile
postimg.org/image/rnp2m1c2r/

***Now my questions are still the same ???***

1> Is there any better library which is not so expensive ?

2> If there is no standard library, can someone point me to conversion logic ? I tried googling but no success. There are few formulas on this site but they don't work or lets call it then they are not simple enough.

Comment: 1100 millis for how many values? 2? 2 billions? Reading the lines from the file will probably be much longer (read several orders of magnitude slower) than parsing the dates anyway, so optimizing the parsing won't lead to any measurable difference.

Comment: If you only measure once, your JVM is not warmed up.  Make a proper benchmark.

Comment: adding more details below..

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any better library which is not so expensive ?

It is far more likely you shouldn't be creating a new SimpleDateFormat every time and you forgot to warmup the code first.  I suggest you run the test for at least 2 seconds after ignoring the first 10,000 runs.

Or it could be that you have confused (ns) nano-seconds with (ms) milli-seconds.

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
static {
    SDF.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String dateTime = SDF.format(new Date());

    long start = 0;
    int warmup = 10000;
    int runs = 1000000;
    for (int i = -warmup; i < runs; i++) {
        if (i == 0)
            start = System.nanoTime();
        long time = SDF.parse(dateTime).getTime();
        if (time < 0) throw new AssertionError();
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("The average time to parse the current time was %,d nano-seconds%n", time / runs);
}
```

prints

```
The average time to parse the current time was 1,250 nano-seconds
```

If 1250 nano-seconds isn't fast enough you can write your own parser.  The fastest I have seen is 100 nano-seconds.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The modern way to handle such time conversions is with the java.time framework. I do not know how it performs in terms of execution speed or garbage-generation, but it should be included in consideration.

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) team also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## Example code

Your Question fails to address the issue of time zone. So I will assume your input strings were intended for [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), and use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class. For other time zones, search Stack Overflow for [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

The [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution up to nanoseconds. Its [`toEpochMilli`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli--) method produces a `long` integer number (64-bit) counting the number of milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 in UTC. Be aware this method involves possible loss of data as any nanoseconds get lopped off when truncated to milliseconds.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss" );
Instant instant = Instant.parse( yourInputStringGoesHere , formatter );
long millisecondsSinceEpochOf1970 = instant.toEpochMilli();
```